# Aws athena / presto string to timestamp

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

How can I parse the following string `2020-07-21 11:19:00.874+00:00`, where +00:00 is the timezone, to a datetime?. I have tried with function `parse_datetime()`, but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this format:

```sql
SELECT parse_datetime('2020-07-21 11:19:00.874+00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ');
```

Comment: It works. Do you have a tip to also manage nanoseconds? ```2020-07-21 11:19:00.874324+00:00``` I tried ```parse_datetime('2020-07-21 11:19:00.874434+00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ')```, but the precision is just miliseconds, isn't it?

Comment: @IgnasiMañé timesamp with nanosecond precision is supported since Presto 335 (see https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-335.html). Athena is based on Presto .172 and it is not clear when they upgrade. However, on AWS you can use Presto directly, using EMR Presto, Starburst Presto or other deployment methods.